# Is 'for' using tail recursion like loop-recur pattern?

Tags: clojure

Traditional approach:

```
(defn make-people [first-names last-names]
  (loop [first-names first-names last-names last-names people []]
    (if (seq first-names)
     (recur
       (rest first-names)
       (rest last-names)
       (conj people {:first (first first-names) :last (first last-names)}))
 people)))
```

Shorter version:

```
(defn shorter-make-people [first-names last-names]
  (for [[first last] (partition 2 (interleave first-names last-names))]
    {:first first :last last}))
```

But I don't have an IDE at hand now to test the performance with large piece of data.

Questions are:

1. Doesn't 'for' do the same thing as 'loop' and 'recur' in this example ?
2. Does it apply to more general cases ?

Any performance testing result is recommended.

Reference source code in core.clj: [for](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4444)
[loop](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L40)

Comment: Be ware that `for` returns a lazy-seq while your `loop`-`recur` produces a realized seq because you didn't explicitly wrap it with a `lazy-seq`.

Answer (score 3):

`for` creates a lazy sequence, i. e. it does not eagerly calculate the result as `loop` does.  Instead it calculates the result incrementally and on demand. This adds significant overhead and performs worse than `loop` (but still in linear time). For that price, lazy sequences offer different benefits, like when processing a lazy sequence you can opt in to not hold the entire sequence in memory at the same time.

http://clojure.org/sequences

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed something but why would it? There is no need for recursion whatsoever in case of `for` comprehension.

Regarding test results:

**make-people**

```
(bench (doall (make-people first-names last-names)))

Evaluation count : 1581540 in 60 samples of 26359 calls.
             Execution time mean : 40.210018 µs
    Execution time std-deviation : 1.838808 µs
   Execution time lower quantile : 37.110371 µs ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 44.515176 µs (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 10.301128 ns

Found 2 outliers in 60 samples (3.3333 %)
    low-severe   2 (3.3333 %)
 Variance from outliers : 31.9497 % Variance is moderately inflated by outliers
```

**even-shorter-make-people**

```
(bench (doall (shorter-make-people first-names last-names)))

Evaluation count : 306180 in 60 samples of 5103 calls.
             Execution time mean : 204.226064 µs
    Execution time std-deviation : 5.726497 µs
   Execution time lower quantile : 196.693866 µs ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 213.226726 µs (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 10.301128 ns
```

**even-shorter-make-people**

```
(defn even-shorter-make-people [first-names last-names]
  (map #(array-map :first %1 :last %2) first-names last-names))

(bench (doall (even-shorter-make-people first-names last-names)))

Evaluation count : 1049880 in 60 samples of 17498 calls.
             Execution time mean : 59.182048 µs
    Execution time std-deviation : 2.338641 µs
   Execution time lower quantile : 56.361840 µs ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 64.056606 µs (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 10.301128 ns
```

Comment: I want to find out how much memory 'for' comprehension use. Where is the limitation for speed and memory. I don't like writing recur everywhere, since it's not concise.

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges in your benchmark.  First one will realize the entire sequence, whereas the second produces only an unrealized lazy sequence.

Comment: @NathanDavis You're of course right. Should be OK now.

Comment: What's the third function?